# Change Backbone data after fetching and before change event is fired

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I fetch data from the server and want to change some string with I18n strings before the subscribers are notified of the model change. Is there a way to add a success method that will always called in first place after fetching data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok found by myself.

```
Model.parse
```

http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-65

Comment: also the fetch({
success:function(){ } 
}); ??

Comment: Sure but with parse, I dont have to care about, it will called after every fetch.

Comment: you also have 1 more option (i know you problem is sorted,but still) , you have a collection.on('reset',your_function(){},this) , even this is triggered when collection fetch completes